# function inside document.ready won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 function fav(type){
    switch(type){
        case "radius":if(radius_fav.indexOf(rad)== -1){
                        radius_fav.push(rad);
                         }
                         break;
        case  "transform":if(transform_fav.indexOf(final_transformation) == -1){transform_fav.push(final_transformation);}
                            break;
        default:if(bshadow !== none && box_fav.indexOf(bshadow) == -1){box_fav.push(bshadow);}  
                        break;                              
    }
    }//end of switch statement


});
```

Inside $(document).ready().This function won't work unless it is put outside document.ready().Any ideas?Jquery tag in html page is included
CONSOLE:
 Uncaught ReferenceError: fav is not defined

Comment: So why you want to put it inside pseudo ready handler? I guess you are facing scope issue, check your console for error

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I have the following function...Inside $(document).ready().This function won't work unless it is put outside document.ready().Any ideas?

It sounds like you're calling the function from an `onXyz` attribute, like this:

```
<div onclick="fav('radius')">...</div>
```

Functions called that way must be *globals*, but when you declare the function within the `ready` callback, it's not a global, it's scoped to the `ready` callback.

Creating globals is best avoided, which is one of the reasons not to use `onXyz` attributes for event hookup. Instead:

```
<div id="radius">...</div>
```

...and then in `ready`:

```
$("#radius").on("click", function() {
    fav('radius');
});
```

...or similar.

You don't have to give these all `id`s, and in fact you may well be able to use the same handler for several of them. for instance:

```
<div class="control" data-type="radius">...</div>
<div class="control" data-type="transform">...</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

then

```
$(".control").on("click", function() {
    fav(this.getAttribute("data-type"));
    // Or:
    // fav($(this).attr("data-type"));
    // But not .data(), that's for something else, not for just accessing data-* attributes
});
```

---

Note that you don't need a `ready` function at all in most cases. Just put a inline-invoked function expression at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag:

```
<script>
(function() {
    $(".control").on("click", function() {
        fav(this.getAttribute("data-type"));
        // Or:
        // fav($(this).attr("data-type"));
        // But not .data(), that's for something else, not for just accessing data-* attributes
    });
})();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You really only need a `ready` handler if you don't control where the `script` tags go.